# WCF error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

This question is not duplicated, please read this carefully.

I have a WCF service and a client, on different machines on the same domain.
The WCF service has the following operation contracts:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPatchService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<PatchUpdateDTO> SearchForUpdates();

    [OperationContract]
    string InstallUpdates();
}
```

`PatchUpdateDTO` class:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class PatchUpdateDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    private string UpdateId { get; }
    [DataMember]
    private string Title { get; }
    [DataMember]
    private string Description { get; }
}
```

The service code for requests listener:

```
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/PatchManagementService");
    _selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PatchService), baseAddress);

    try
    {
        _selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPatchService), new WSHttpBinding(), "PatchService");

        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        _selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        _selfHost.Open();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
    ...
    }
```

I have added the service reference in my client application.

The client code :

```
public class AgentCommunicationWCFProvider : IAgentComminicationProvider
{
    private readonly PatchServiceClient _patchManagementService;

    public AgentCommunicationWCFProvider()
    {
        _patchManagementService = new PatchServiceClient();
    }
    public string InstallUpdates()
    {
        return _patchManagementService.InstallUpdates();
    }

    public List<PatchUpdateDTO> SearchForUpdates()
    {
        return _patchManagementService.SearchForUpdates();
    }
```

}

The client configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPatchService" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://someIpAddress:8000/PatchManagementService/PatchService"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPatchService"
          contract="PatchManagementServiceReference.IPatchService" name="WSHttpBinding_IPatchService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="****" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Now something odd is happening, when using the InstallUpdates() method I get a return string and it is working fine, but when using the SearchForUpdates() method, that suppose to return `List<PatchUpdateDTO>`, I get the following error:

Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
http://**someIpAddress**:8000/PatchManagementService/PatchService. 
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server 
(possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Any ideas why it has a problem with a complex object?

Comment: Get rid of [Serializable] attribute and try again. You already have DataContract and DataMember attributes on the class and properties so why would you use [Serializable] on the top? The problem seems to be in this area becuase the InstallUpdates() just retuns a string which WCF understands by default.

Comment: Why your PatchUpdateDTO class has private properties? They should be public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - I have just copied your code and found the following changes:

1. Get rid of `[Serializable]` attribute.
   If you want to use DataContract/DataMember attributes, otherwise keep it but 
   delete DataContract/DataMember and all properties will autometically be 
   serialisable.
2. Change the access modifier `'private'` to `public` for all properties of
   `PatchUpdateDTO` class otherwise you wont be able to access them in the client 
    application.
3. Add the setter `set;` to all the properties of `PatchUpdateDTO` class 
   otherwise you wont be able to set the values outside of `PatchUpdateDTO` class
4. On the client config, change **someIpAddress** to the localhost or to the IP.
   address of the machine where WCF service is running.

After above changes it works on my machine and returns the list of PatchUpdateDTO objects.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, the modifier change from private to public made it worked